# Hiding a cursor in chrome for touch screen kiosk

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, cursor

I have a bunch of museum touch-screen kiosks running chrome, and I have the cursors disabled like so:

```
*{
    -webkit-user-select: none !important;
    cursor: url(../img/cursor.png), none !important;
}
```

cursor.png is a single pixel 1% opacity image.

This works well 90% of the time. But sometimes the cursor comes back on its own. Possible when ever a maintenance script to reload the UI is run.

Is there a way to really tell chrome: "I dont care what you think, I dont ever want to see a cursor appearing"?

It would be great if you could put chrome in touch screen mode using a flag to take care of this.

Im using Chrome 20, and running OSX 10.7.4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On the internet I did not find any 100% solution for Chrome specifically. What I would try (if the situation let's you) is change the cursor on the Windows level. In the configuration panel you can change the cursor's appereance.

By using a transparent cursor like [this](http://pc.autons.net/stuff/blanks/), you are quite certain the cursor stays invisible and does not pop back up. Of course it is not specifically for Chrome, but perhaps it fits your situation as well.